# Finding out the type from an uninitialized typed property

Tags: php, oop

I have the following code in my `User` class:

```php
class User {
    
    public int $id = 0;
    public string $code;
    public string $name;
}
```

When assigning `$code` from the database, I need to find out what type the var is before I can assign it, so I use `gettype()`, in the `__construct` function for `User`:

```
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    settype($val, gettype($this->$key));
    $this->$key = $val;
}
```

However it returns this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property User::$code must not be accessed before initialization

I understand what the error message means.

Is there a way to find out the casted type of the variable before its been set?

Comment: Before the value has been set, the variable effectively has no type.

Comment: Not sure if this approach is particular helpful. It means that a class with specific data has to keep on checking it's own datatypes - a huge overhead (IMHO).

Comment: @DonR I don't see the point in type casting it then, if it has no type at __construct but I've declared it, Why i can't I check what it is?

Comment: @NigelRen Which approach are you refering to?

Comment: The idea of having to find out the type of a field in a class through reflection (as the answer proposes) is a huge overhead (sorry no figures) when you should know the types of fields in a class you are working with.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes I do know the values, but the `$data` array I am looping through is pulled from the database.  For some reason PDO pulls all data from the database into strings, Which means that I need to check what the variable is before i assign it.

Comment: So, __the real problem__ is that PDO gives you strings. Maybe you should solve this problem instead?

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, the problem is I can't change that without breaking all the domains on the server and it is a very long winded problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are attempting to do, and without knowing more about the whole thing I won't risk an opinion about the logic of it.

Putting that aside, using `gettype()` on an uninitialized typed property won't work, because the property has effectively no value at that point.

*But*, since the property is typed, you could get the property defined type via reflection:

```
class User {
    
    public int $id = 0;
    public string $code;
    public string $name;
    
    public function __construct() {
        
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $props   = $reflect->getProperties();
        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            echo $prop->getType()->getName(), "\n";            
        }

    }
}

new User();
```

The above would [output](https://3v4l.org/7UtO4D#v7.4.0):

```
int
string
string
```

Doing this on the fly seems like a lot of overhead, so please make sure that there is no better tool at your disposal. Doing this kind of thing on the `__construct()` method does not look very wise at first sight, but of course I do not know your specific constraints.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know about that.  Thanks.  It seems a lot of workaround though when they could just let me check on the type before it's had a value assigned to it though!

Comment: No, because it has no type before anything is assigned. It's `uninitilized`, which is different from `null` well. You could even say that the object at that point is on an invalid state, since the properties do not have a value that match their declared type. Again, I don't want to venture an opinion about what you are trying to do because I can imagine there _could_ be a valid use case for something like this (although I guess it would happen very rarely within the class itself), but what you are attempting do do seems a bit convoluted and risky at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable as

```
$foo;
```

then it is `null` until it is successfully initialized, so it has no type.

If it is a typed property, then it is simply uninitialized, not null. **The rest of my answer contains some experiments conducted based on the information received in the comment-section**. So, a variable or property is `null` before it is initialized, with the exception of typed properties, which are simply uninitialized.

In the comment section it was suggested that the uninitialized variable does not equal to `null`. So I have written this test code:

```
<?php

$foo;
echo var_dump($foo === null);
```

and executed it

[image]

It gives a warning and evaluates to `true`, so the uninitialized variable was indeed `null`.

Since yivi pointed out that the question refers to a property, I have conducted another experiment:

```
<?php

class Foo {
        public $foo;
        public function __construct() {
            echo var_dump($this->foo === null);
        }
}

new Foo();
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly right. An initialized property does not have a value of `null`. It's simply `uninitialized`. Comparing it with `null` would fail as well.

Comment: @yivi have you tried your hypothesis? I have written a test code and executed it. The result implies that the uninitialized variable is `null` indeed, even though referring to it prompts a warning. I have added the details to my answer.

Comment: Question is asking about a **property**, not a variable. Try it again with a **typed** property.

Comment: Maybe reading the whole question would help. These are **TYPED** properties the question is about. Your example does not fit the question.

Comment: @yivi you are correct. Tried that as well and the result was suggesting that you are right. Edited my answer accordingly.